# Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qwidget

Everywhere only just "before QPaintDevice" questions and nowhere is my error. So, here we go.

I need an extern QWidget to be able to get access to it from outside (because I don't know any other ways to do it). Basically, I need this: Create 2 QWidgets from 1 window, go to first window and from there hide main window and show second window created by main window (although main window is not main(), it is QWidget too).

I added

```
extern QWidget *widget = new QWidget
```

everywhere and everyhow in possible ways, and I still got this message. I suppose, it means that I need to create my QApplication (in main.cpp) and only then declare any QWidgets. But then HOW can I access those QWidgets from another QWidgets?

Code is here:
https://github.com/ewancoder/game/tree/QWidget_before_QApp_problem

P.S. The final goal is to be able show and hide both gamewindow.cpp and world.cpp from battle.cpp (just regular class)

And btw, adding Q_OBJECT and #include  both don't work.

Anyway, if I cannot use functions from one window to another, than what's the point? I can have one window in another, and then another in that one, and then one in that another... but I can't do anything from the last to the previous. After years on Delphi that seems strange to me.

Comment: I've never encountered a valid use case of 'extern' in a C++/Qt program. The proper way would be either have the main window do the management and have the children send their hide/show requests for the other widget via a signal/slot connection, or pass the pointers to the widgets to be managed to the widget that wants to hide them. (I.e. store the pointers as members in the managing widget)

Comment: Childrens can't use their's parents functions (like hide or show), I've tried already do that. So, the only way is going to be signal/slot connections, right? They just looks strange to me as I explore QT world and I could not make them work yet either. Anyway, thx for the direction, I'll google some more info about connections.

Comment: You can also pass the parent as a pointer to the child and call e.g. show/hide from there. Although it's often bad style and causes cyclic dependencies to let the child windows/widgets know about the main window.

Comment: Oh, right. Gotta try this. Thx again, can be a gr8 option for quick fix. But in long perspective, I want to write valid good-style c++.
UPD: I can just store pointer in global variable to be able to connect from any class.

Comment: Well, I come up to the same error. I cannot use any variables, pointers and etc. of type QWidget before application actually running <QApplication>.

Comment: @EwanCoder What you really need to do is look at examples that come with Qt. Seriously. Just do it. Since you have no C++ background, that will give you a head start. Examples are trivial to access from Qt Creator, just open them, and hit Ctrl-R to run them. Then look at how they are written. You should pick up the relevant patterns in C++ fairly quickly that way. C++ is nothing like Delphi - I used BP and Delphi quite extensively, and C++ required a clean start.

Comment: I just need some solution to twist things like in Delphi. I know lots of different programming languages alongside c and delphi (but not much coded with c itself)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use extern or otherwise static variables which lead to creation of the widget before the QApplication is created in main. The QApplication must exist before the constructor of the QWidget is executed.

Instead of sharing the variable via extern, either make the other windows members of the main window, and then make the windows known to each other by passing around pointers, or keep them private in MainWindow and request the actions from the subwindows e.g. via signal/slots. As a generic rule, don't use global variables but class members.

In the following FirstWindow (which is supposed hide main window and secondWindow) gets the main window and the second window passed via pointers and then just calls show/hide on them directly.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

In main window, have two members for the two other windows, say FirstWindow and SecondWindow:
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
        ...
    private:
        FirstWindow *m_firstWindow;
        SecondWindow *m_secondWindow;
    };

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
     m_firstWindow = new FirstWindow; //not pass this as parent as you want to hide the main window while the others are visible)
     m_secondWindow = new SecondWindow;
     m_firstWindow->setMainWindow(this);
     m_firstWindow->setSecond(m_secondWindow);
     m_firstWindow->show(); //Show first window immediately, leave second window hidden
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
     //Manual deletion is necessary as no parent is passed. Alternatively, use QScopedPointer
     delete m_firstWindow;
     delete m_secondWindow;
}
```

FirstWindow, inline for brevity:

```
class FirstWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FirstWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {}

    void setMainWindow(MainWindow *mainWindow) { m_mainWindow = mainWindow); }
    void setSecondWindow(SecondWindow *secondWindow) { m_secondWindow = secondWindow; }

private Q_SLOTS:
     void somethingHappened() { //e.g. some button was clicked
         m_mainWindow->hide();
         m_secondWindow->show();
     }
private: 
     MainWindow* m_mainWindow;
     SecondWindow* m_secondWindow;  
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not helping the former author, but others facing the problem. 
I simply got this error by mistaking a debug-library with a release one. So check your linker settings, if you are sure the implementation is done right (first instancing application and then using widgets).

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Auto-answer: Check that you are compiling the release version instead of the debug one.