# Simple Input Dialog in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, startup, qapplication

I am writing a program which checks if user is root. If not an input dialog shows up for password. I have done this earlier too (inside some class) but lost the file somewhere.

```
if os.name == 'posix':
  if not os.getuid() == 0:
    input, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Password',
                                                   'Enter password:', QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
  if ok:
    #remaining code
```

The issue here is that this produces an error `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice`

Is it only possible to bring up input dialog using UI class? or Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590421/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qwidget)

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt gave use the whole code but it seems that you are not following the basic guidelines of PyQt.
Here is the minimum you need to have to create a correct pyqt app:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidget

def main():
    app = QtWidget.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidget.SOMEWIDGET()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What I want is to get only input dialog for typing password. With the above example how do I get the input dialog. The most example available in the net deals with `class Example(QtGui.QWidget):`. But in my case I just only need the input dialog.