# QMessageBox in a shared library throwing error

Tags: c++, qt, static, qt4, shared-libraries

I created a shared library in QT to create a user defined static message box with following modules selected (class code given below). QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets. But it is throwing error.

Below is the library class that is throwing error.

//Header File

```
class Q_DECL_EXPORT cMessageBox
    {
      private:
           static QMessageBox msgbox;
      public:
           cMessageBox();
           ~cMessageBox();
           static void CustomMessageBox(QString strTitle,QString strMessage);
    };
```

//CPP file

```
QMessageBox cMessageBox::msgbox;

cMessageBox::cMessageBox(){}

cMessageBox::~cMessageBox(){}

void cMessageBox::CustomMessageBox(QString strTitle, QString strMessage){
     msgbox.setWindowTitle(strTitle);
     msgbox.setText(strMessage);
     msgbox.exec();
}
```

//Used as

```
cMessageBox::CustomMessageBox("Title","Message");
```

Error is

[

QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

exited with code 3

]

If i remove the static for both the QMessageBox and the CustomMessageBox method, then it is working fine (library used code given below). What error i did, when 
using static keyword.

```
cMessageBox msg;
msg.CustomMessageBox("Title","Message");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, static objects are initialized before the main method runs. Hence, `QApplication` is never initialized before you make `QMessagebox` object. Hence, we usually don't create static `QWidgets`. (I don't know a remedy to that)
This may not solve your problem. But at least we know what is wrong.

See this for more info.

[Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590421/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qwidget)

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
int argc = 1;
char* argv[] = { (char*)"", NULL };
QApplication app(argc,argv);//(argc, argv);

QMessageBox mb(QMessageBox::Question,
               "Check card in reader",
               "Card connected?",
               QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
if(mb.exec() == QMessageBox::Ok)
{
    return 1;//TRUE
} else {
    return 0;//FALSE
}
```